# CSS inline-block not working?

Tags: html, navbar, css

You can't imagine how frustrating it is to just create simple codes and they don't work :( 
i want this code make the nav horiz. and set width to each a to separate between them

HTML:

```
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
body{margin:0;}   ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;}
li{float:left;}   a{width:60;}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want them all on the same line, it happens.

Comment: Yeah, it would help if we knew what it is you're looking to do ;)

Comment: Expected and actual behavior, please? Right now we have absolutely no clue what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be wanting your links to all be 60px wide. If that's the case, change:

```
a{width:60;}
```

To:

```
a { width: 60px; display: inline-block;}
```

'60' on its own isn't a recognised measurement for a CSS width, and you need inline-block to stop it from just being treated like a line of text.

However if you want to improve on this, and make each link separated by the same amount (as it is, some links are closer together than others), I'd put a margin on the li, like this:

```
li { margin-right: 40px; }
```

Comment: this didn't work either :( all on vertical line and of course no width

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HsDRy/

Comment: but what about the whole area isnot clickable ???

Comment: You never said that's what you wanted...

Comment: Anyway, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HsDRy/1/ The borders are black just to illustrate where the links start and end, and you can change the padding. I think it's more like what you want, but do remember that you didn't specify that from the beginning so I wasn't to know.

Comment: i know i didn't specify that :( thanx for helping me out NOW U R MY HERO :)

Comment: can i ask one more question {SORRY} hoe to fill it all wide long in the browser i tried the div's width = 100% but no work

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HsDRy/2/

Comment: ok From now on i won't ask anybody except the "EXPERT" {SharkofMirkwood} :D :D :D :D

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want to do here really... I agree with SharkofMirkwood i suppose. Use:

```
a { width: 60px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 10px;}
```

Adding some margin will help space them out. Also, use the [:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) to prevent the last list-item anchor from breaking the nav. Check out the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Getting_Started). It might help you understand how this all works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want it to display inline (all in one row).
If that is the case you need to add the display attribute to your li
you can use inline or inline-block, for that purpose.

example:
li{float:left;display:inline;}

Comment: That worked for me :) but :( the "block" value don't work and it doesn't get the whole link area is clickable